# How to add a icons on the Quick Launch?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I an struggling to add icon in the Quick launch.

I got the below code was able to add a colaps and expand feature to the Quick launch.

CSS

```
/* Default menu levels 3+ padding */
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item { padding-left: 60px; }
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item { padding-left: 80px; }
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item { padding-left: 100px; }

/* Switch level 2+ padding */
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch { padding-left: 20px; }
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch { padding-left: 40px; }
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch { padding-left: 60px; }
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch { padding-left: 80px; }

/* Collapsed and expanded levels */
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li ul {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.expanded > ul {
    height: auto;
}

/* Switch styles */
.switch {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.switch span {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.switch img {
    position: relative;
    left: -254px;
    top: -184px;
}
.expanded > .switch img{
    left: -254px;
    top: -144px;
}
```

JS

```
var SP2013QLAccordion = {

    // Options
    useAnimation: true, // Animation is supported in IE9+
    collapseOtherLevels: false, // Collapse sibling levels on expanding
    expandTransition: 'height 0.15s ease-out',
    collapseTransition: 'height 0.15s ease-out',

    // Initialization function
    init: function () {
        var levels = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li');

        if (levels.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
                if (levels[i].querySelector('ul')) {

                    // Create switch elements and append them to levels with sublevels
                    var switchSpan = document.createElement('div');

                    switchSpan.className = 'switch';
                    switchSpan.innerHTML = '<span><img alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png"/></span>';
                    levels[i].insertBefore(switchSpan, levels[i].firstChild);

                    // Add 'expanded' class to selected branch and 'collapsed' to all other
                    levels[i].className += (levels[i].querySelector('.selected') || levels[i].className.indexOf('selected') != -1) ? ' expanded' : ' collapsed';
                }
                if (levels[i].querySelector('li')) {

                    // Create switch elements and append them to levels with sublevels
                    var switchSpan = document.createElement('div');

                    switchSpan.className = 'switch';
                    switchSpan.innerHTML = '<span><img alt="" src="https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/IT/KnowledgeCenter/_layouts/15/images/EMMTerm.png"/></span>';
                    levels[i].insertBefore(switchSpan, levels[i].firstChild);

                    // Add 'expanded' class to selected branch and 'collapsed' to all other
                    //  levels[i].className += (levels[i].querySelector('.selected') || levels[i].className.indexOf('selected') != -1) ? ' expanded' : ' collapsed';
                }
            }

            // Detect IE8 or lower to turn off animation
            if (document.all && !document.addEventListener) SP2013QLAccordion.useAnimation = false;

            var switches = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox .switch');
            // Add collapse/expand event to switch nodes
            if (switches.length) {
                for (var j = 0; j < switches.length; j++) {
                    AddEvent(switches[j], 'click', ExpandCollapse);
                }
            }
        }

        // Function to get height of a hidden node
        function CalculateHeight(node) {
            var initialStyles = node.style.cssText,
              nodeHeight;

            node.style.position = 'absolute';
            node.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            node.style.height = 'auto';
            nodeHeight = node.offsetHeight;
            node.style.cssText = initialStyles;
            return nodeHeight;
        }

        // Expand/Collapse function
        function ExpandCollapse(param) {
            var level = this.parentNode,
              sublevel = level.querySelector('ul'),
              sublevelHeight = CalculateHeight(sublevel),
              otherLevels = level.parentElement.children;

            // Close other levels on expanding
            if (SP2013QLAccordion.collapseOtherLevels && level.className.indexOf('collapsed') != -1 && !param) {
                for (var i = 0; i < otherLevels.length; i++) {
                    if (otherLevels[i].className.indexOf('expanded') != -1) ExpandCollapse.call(otherLevels[i], 'collapse');
                }
            }

            if (SP2013QLAccordion.useAnimation) {
                // Animated collapse
                if (level.className.indexOf('expanded') != -1 || param == 'collapse') {
                    sublevel.style.height = sublevelHeight + 'px';
                    level.className = level.className.replace(' expanded', ' collapsed');
                    sublevel.style.transition = SP2013QLAccordion.collapseTransition;
                    sublevel.offsetHeight; // Force repaint
                    sublevel.style.height = 0;
                    // Animated expand
                } else {
                    sublevel.style.height = 0;
                    level.className = level.className.replace(' collapsed', ' expanded');
                    sublevel.style.transition = SP2013QLAccordion.expandTransition;
                    sublevel.offsetHeight; // Force repaint
                    sublevel.style.height = sublevelHeight + 'px';
                    sublevel.addEventListener('transitionend', function transitionEnd(event) {
                        if (event.propertyName == 'height') {
                            sublevel.removeAttribute('style');
                            sublevel.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd, false);
                        }
                    }, false);
                }
            } else {
                // Not animated collapse
                if (level.className.indexOf('expanded') != -1 || param == 'collapse') {
                    level.className = level.className.replace(' expanded', ' collapsed');
                    // Not animated expand
                } else {
                    level.className = level.className.replace(' collapsed', ' expanded');
                }
            }
        }

        // Crossbrowser event attachment helper function
        function AddEvent(htmlElement, eventName, eventFunction) {
            if (htmlElement.attachEvent)
                htmlElement.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function () { eventFunction.call(htmlElement); });
            else if (htmlElement.addEventListener)
                htmlElement.addEventListener(eventName, eventFunction, false);
        }
    }
};

// SharePoint default DOM onLoad function
ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(SP2013QLAccordion.init);
```

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add CSS for the element which you want.

Here is sample code as you don't describe so details.

```
<style>
        /* Default menu levels 3+ padding */
        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item {
            padding-left: 60px;
        }

        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item {
            padding-left: 80px;
        }

        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item {
            padding-left: 100px;
        }

        /* Switch level 2+ padding */
        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch {
            padding-left: 40px;
        }

        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch {
            padding-left: 60px;
        }

        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > ul.static > li.static > .switch {
            padding-left: 80px;
        }

        /* Collapsed and expanded levels */
        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li ul {
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.expanded > ul {
            height: auto;
        }

        /* Switch styles */
        .switch {
            float: left;
            width: 20px;
            height: 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

            .switch span {
                display: block;
                width: 10px;
                height: 15px;
                margin: 5px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .switch img {
                position: relative;
                left: -254px;
                top: -184px;
            }

        .expanded > .switch img {
            left: -254px;
            top: -144px;
        }
        .NavImage{
            background-image:url(https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/IT/KnowledgeCenter/_layouts/15/images/EMMTerm.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position-x:20px;
            background-position-y:6px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var SP2013QLAccordion = {

            // Options
            useAnimation: true, // Animation is supported in IE9+
            collapseOtherLevels: false, // Collapse sibling levels on expanding
            expandTransition: 'height 0.15s ease-out',
            collapseTransition: 'height 0.15s ease-out',

            // Initialization function
            init: function () {
                var levels = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li');

                if (levels.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
                        if (levels[i].querySelector('ul')) {

                            // Create switch elements and append them to levels with sublevels
                            var switchSpan = document.createElement('div');

                            switchSpan.className = 'switch';
                            switchSpan.innerHTML = '<span><img alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png"/></span>';
                            levels[i].insertBefore(switchSpan, levels[i].firstChild);

                            // Add 'expanded' class to selected branch and 'collapsed' to all other
                            levels[i].className += (levels[i].querySelector('.selected') || levels[i].className.indexOf('selected') != -1) ? ' expanded' : ' collapsed';
                        }
                        if (levels[i].querySelector('li')) {

                            //Create switch elements and append them to levels with sublevels
                            var switchSpan = document.createElement('div');

                            switchSpan.className = 'switch';
                            switchSpan.innerHTML = '<span><img alt="" src="https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/IT/KnowledgeCenter/_layouts/15/images/EMMTerm.png"/></span>';
                            levels[i].insertBefore(switchSpan, levels[i].firstChild);

                            // Add 'expanded' class to selected branch and 'collapsed' to all other
                            //  levels[i].className += (levels[i].querySelector('.selected') || levels[i].className.indexOf('selected') != -1) ? ' expanded' : ' collapsed';
                        }
                    }

                    // Detect IE8 or lower to turn off animation
                    if (document.all && !document.addEventListener) SP2013QLAccordion.useAnimation = false;

                    var switches = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox .switch');
                    // Add collapse/expand event to switch nodes
                    if (switches.length) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < switches.length; j++) {
                            AddEvent(switches[j], 'click', ExpandCollapse);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Function to get height of a hidden node
                function CalculateHeight(node) {
                    var initialStyles = node.style.cssText,
                      nodeHeight;

                    node.style.position = 'absolute';
                    node.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    node.style.height = 'auto';
                    nodeHeight = node.offsetHeight;
                    node.style.cssText = initialStyles;
                    return nodeHeight;
                }

                // Expand/Collapse function
                function ExpandCollapse(param) {
                    var level = this.parentNode,
                      sublevel = level.querySelector('ul'),
                      sublevelHeight = CalculateHeight(sublevel),
                      otherLevels = level.parentElement.children;

                    // Close other levels on expanding
                    if (SP2013QLAccordion.collapseOtherLevels && level.className.indexOf('collapsed') != -1 && !param) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < otherLevels.length; i++) {
                            if (otherLevels[i].className.indexOf('expanded') != -1) ExpandCollapse.call(otherLevels[i], 'collapse');
                        }
                    }

                    if (SP2013QLAccordion.useAnimation) {
                        // Animated collapse
                        if (level.className.indexOf('expanded') != -1 || param == 'collapse') {
                            sublevel.style.height = sublevelHeight + 'px';
                            level.className = level.className.replace(' expanded', ' collapsed');
                            sublevel.style.transition = SP2013QLAccordion.collapseTransition;
                            sublevel.offsetHeight; // Force repaint
                            sublevel.style.height = 0;
                            // Animated expand
                        } else {
                            sublevel.style.height = 0;
                            level.className = level.className.replace(' collapsed', ' expanded');
                            sublevel.style.transition = SP2013QLAccordion.expandTransition;
                            sublevel.offsetHeight; // Force repaint
                            sublevel.style.height = sublevelHeight + 'px';
                            sublevel.addEventListener('transitionend', function transitionEnd(event) {
                                if (event.propertyName == 'height') {
                                    sublevel.removeAttribute('style');
                                    sublevel.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd, false);
                                }
                            }, false);
                            var lis = level.querySelectorAll('li');
                            if (lis.length) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
                                    lis[i].classList.add("NavImage");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Not animated collapse
                        if (level.className.indexOf('expanded') != -1 || param == 'collapse') {
                            level.className = level.className.replace(' expanded', ' collapsed');
                            // Not animated expand
                        } else {
                            level.className = level.className.replace(' collapsed', ' expanded');
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Crossbrowser event attachment helper function
                function AddEvent(htmlElement, eventName, eventFunction) {
                    if (htmlElement.attachEvent)
                        htmlElement.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function () { eventFunction.call(htmlElement); });
                    else if (htmlElement.addEventListener)
                        htmlElement.addEventListener(eventName, eventFunction, false);
                }
            }
        };

        // SharePoint default DOM onLoad function
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(SP2013QLAccordion.init);
    </script>
```

Result:
[image]